# Searching in multiple APIs

Tags: performance, api, rest, architecture

I come across a problem that I have no clue where should I start in order to solve it.

I have a service that searchs for something very usual, for instance, the current dollar cotation in Brazil. I have multiple trust Apis that can provide me this information, but response time is critical to my service, so I have to choose the faster API, always.

Do anyone knows where do I get started here? Any clue would be great. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I would go with parallel asynchronous requests on the different API you think are the best.

Then you only treat the first response.